# Android virtual device won't work

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Hello guys i have problem in eclipse i can't use android virtual device 
please help me to fix this problem if you want to know more info about my problem please replie 
and sorry for my bad english

link of photo 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nexr.png

**info :** 
**OS : win 8.1 Pro**

**ADT Verssion : 23.0.2**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Kge.png

Answer (score 0):

Read below the API version, you have no system image installed for the selected target (4.4). If a target is available for the emulator, you will be able to find it in the SDK manager.

By image, I mean an emulator image, e.g. an arm or atom (x86) image for the specified android api target.

Comment: @user3730303   No, unless you are using 4.4.2. In your screenshot, it shows that you have 4.4W selected, in which case you would need the wearables atom image under 4.4W (W for wearables). If though, you are indeed using 4.4.2, then you are correct.

Comment: @user3730303 also, keep in mind that to use the atom image, your machine has to support it. ARM is a more standard (but slower) image.